# Handle HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request in Cucumber RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, httpclient, resttemplate, http-status-code-400

Hi I have written a Cucumber test case where i send a POST request with an XML body, output of that request is 400 Error with an XML body, which is expected and when i throw the request i get that too, but what i get is below:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:709)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:462)
    at uk.co.argos.services.order.StepDefinations.TestMethods.POSTrestTemplatewithXML(TestMethods.java:147)
    at uk.co.argos.services.order.StepDefinations.StepDefs.user_hits_the_getSlot_request_with_OrderEnricher_with_and_and(StepDefs.java:118)
    at ✽.Given User hits the getSlot request with OrderEnricher with "2020-40-32" and "150" and "MK92NW"(OrderEnricher_Negative.feature:5)
```

And my test step failes with bad request, But ideally that is my expected and i want to pass my test step & scenario, not sure how should i handle it, i have tried applying multiple things. Can anyone help please?

```
 public static ResponseEntity<String> POSTrestTemplatewithXML(URI uri, String XMLforPOST){
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters=new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
            messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
            HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            HttpEntity<String> request=new HttpEntity<String>(XMLforPOST, headers);
            responseEntity=restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);



        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("RESPONSE-"  +responseEntity);
            byte[] bytes = ((HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest)e).getResponseBodyAsByteArray();
            assertTrue(true);

//Convert byte[] to String
            String s = new String(bytes);

            System.out.println(s);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: If the BadRequest is the expected behaviour of your application, wouldn't it make more sense to test this in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your catch method like following :

```
try{
  //your code
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Hi Selçuk Ayhan, thanks for the comment, I Tried, it still gives the same error, which is expected but it should pass my test step

Comment: It catches the exception perfectly, but what should i do so that it pass my test step after catching the exception